# Numpy Array Shape issue in Web Server with Keras DNN on Higgs Boson Kaggle

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am creating a Python web server with [japronto](https://github.com/squeaky-pl/japronto) in order to serve results from a Keras neural network trained on the Kaggle higgs boson dataset.  I get this in the logs of the server:

```
# print(data)

[ 0.86929321 -0.63508183  0.22569026  0.32747006 -0.6899932   0.75420225
 -0.24857314 -1.0920639   0.          1.37499213 -0.65367419  0.93034911
  1.10743606  1.13890433 -1.57819831 -1.04698539  0.          0.65792954
 -0.01045457 -0.04576717  3.10196137  1.35376     0.97956312  0.97807616
  0.92000484  0.72165745  0.98875093  0.87667835]

# print(data.shape)

(28,)

# The exception:
output = model.predict(data)
  File "/Users/david/PycharmProjects/server/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1817, in predict
check_batch_axis=False)
  File "/Users/david/PycharmProjects/server/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 123, in _standardize_input_data
str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking : expected input_1 
    to have shape (28,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

I also wrote a standalone script and it produces the same exception:

```
model = load_model('models/keras-higgs.h5')

test_data = np.array([0.86929321, -0.63508183,  0.22569026,  0.32747006, -0.6899932,  0.75420225,
                      -0.24857314, -1.0920639,   0.,          1.37499213, -0.65367419, 0.93034911,
                      1.10743606,  1.13890433, -1.57819831, -1.04698539,  0.,         0.65792954,
                      -0.01045457, -0.04576717,  3.10196137,  1.35376,     0.97956312, 0.97807616,
                      0.92000484,  0.72165745,  0.98875093,  0.87667835])
print(test_data.shape) # (28, )
result = model.predict(test_data) # ValueError
print(result)
```

The neural net is structured as follows:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense

input_layer = Input(shape=(28, ))
hidden_layer_1 = Dense(24, activation='sigmoid')(input_layer)
hidden_layer_2 = Dense(20, activation='sigmoid')(hidden_layer_1)
hidden_layer_3 = Dense(16, activation='sigmoid')(hidden_layer_2)
hidden_layer_4 = Dense(12, activation='sigmoid')(hidden_layer_3)
output_layer = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(hidden_layer_4)

model = Model(input_layer, output_layer)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(measurements, labels, epochs=500, batch_size=256)
model.save('../models/keras-higgs.h5')
```

The Japronto server is defined as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from japronto import Application
from json import JSONDecodeError
from keras.models import load_model

model = load_model('models/keras-higgs.h5')

def higgs(request):
    try:
        data = np.array(request.json)
        print(data)
        print(data.shape)
        output = model.predict(data)
    except JSONDecodeError:
        return request.Response(code=400)
    return request.Response(json=output)

app = Application()
app.router.add_route('/higgs', higgs, 'POST')
app.run(debug=True)
```

The `ValueError` is odd because clearly the `shape=(28, )` from the logging.  What am I doing wrong here and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the print, seems like you have a numpy array; the shape (28,) can be misleading.

Simply do `data = data.reshape((1,28))` to reshape the input into a proper nd-array with the required shape.

Comment: Thanks, Cihan, I tried that `data = data.reshape((28, 1))
print(data.shape)` which prints `(28, 1)`.  But still I get `ValueError: Error when checking : expected input_1 to have shape (28,) but got array with shape (1,)`

Comment: @mobiusinversion actually it looks like keras expects (m_train, n_features) shaped inputs. Could you try data = data.reshape((1,28)) instead?

Comment: Hye Cihan, I was just logging in to post an update, I looked in `training.py:1815` and saw `x = _standardize_input_data(x, self._feed_input_names, self._feed_input_shapes, check_batch_axis=False)`.  So yes, that works, I changed: `data = data.reshape((1, 28))`.  Do you want to edit the answer and I can accept it?